# Confusion about SSOP-28 ZIF socket

Tags: zif

I recently purchased [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09T6154ZK) SSOP-28 ZIF socket to program some PIC24FJ32GU202-I/SS. To my surprise, the part doesn't seem to fit. When I push down on the top of the package, the top layer "mandibles" (pins) open up wide and you can see an internal/lower layer of pins. I would assume I should gently lay my chip onto the lower level of pins, then release the spring-top, at which point the top pins and bottom pins clamp down on the chip leads.

What is actually happening: The chip is slightly wider than the top layer pins, even when fully expanded, meaning I can't possibly get the part onto the lower pins. Releasing the spring-top in that state, the chip is still loose and not making an electrical connection.

Just wondering if I'm missing a step...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without drawings and dimensions it’s hard to say 100% but I’ve purchased similar fixtures for many packages over the years and I have had to make sure to order a socket that will fit the dimensions of the particular package I am using.

Most SSOP28 packages I’ve used are ~5-5.6mm body width. But the Sunroom SSOP28 #5412 socket specifies 4.4mm width. Their #54

I suspect the socket you have is made for a different size package.